# PHP array comparison and finding matched and non matched items

Tags: php

I have been using this script for finding matched and nonmatched array items.

My code is.

```
$filter1 = "red,green,blue,yellow";         
$parts1 = explode(',', $filter1);

$filter2 = "red,green,blue";        
$parts2 = explode(',', $filter2);

for($i=0; $i< count($parts1); $i++)
{

    for($j=0; $j< count($parts2); $j++)
    {

        if($parts1[$i] == $parts2[$j])
        {
            $match[] = $parts1[$i];
        } else {
            $nomatch[] = $parts1[$i];
        }
    }
}

print_r($match);
echo "<br>";
print_r($nomatch);
```

By using this code i am only getting the matched items and not nonmatched. Can anybody help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)? [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)? What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 6):

You can try using `array_intersect` and `array_diff`

```
$filter1 = "red,green,blue,yellow";         
$parts1 = explode(',', $filter1);

$filter2 = "red,green,blue";        
$parts2 = explode(',', $filter2);

$match = array_intersect($parts1, $parts2);
$nomatch = array_diff($parts1, $parts2);

var_dump($match,$nomatch);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'red' (length=3)
  1 => string 'green' (length=5)
  2 => string 'blue' (length=4)
array
  3 => string 'yellow' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 3):

this can be done by  [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$filter1 = "red,green,blue,yellow";         
$parts1 = explode(',', $filter1);

$filter2 = "red,green,blue";        
$parts2 = explode(',', $filter2);


$result = array_intersect($parts1 , $parts2 );
print_r($result);
```

[**Live Example**](http://codepad.org/DXNBHuZY)

> [image]

and

```
$result = array_diff($parts1 , $parts2 );

print_r($result);
```

[**LIVE example**](http://codepad.org/DFsPMcCj)

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

because your nested loop not run at yellow color time 
try this

```
$filter1 = "red,green,blue,yellow";    
$filter2 = "red,green,blue,gray";
```

or

```
for($j=0; $j<= count($parts2); $j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filter1 = "red,green,blue,yellow";         
$parts1 = explode(',', $filter1);

$filter2 = "red,green,blue";    
$parts2 = explode(',', $filter2);   

$match = array();
$nomatch = array();

foreach($parts1 as $v){     
    if(in_array($v,$parts2))
        $match[]=$v;
    else
        $nomatch[]=$v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$filter1 = "red,green,blue,yellow";         
$parts1 = explode(',', $filter1);

$filter2 = "red,green,blue";        
$parts2 = explode(',', $filter2);

foreach($parts1 as $first)
{
    if(in_array($first, $parts2))
    {
        $match[] = $first;
    }
    else 
    {
        $nomatch[] = $first;
    }
}

print_r($match);
echo "<br>";
print_r($nomatch);
```

or you can use array_diff to get non matched items

```
print_r(array_diff($parts1,$parts2));
```

and for matched items use

```
print_r(array_intersect($parts1,$parts2));
```

Comment: Actually i want to use strpos for comparing string values

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to use this if statement if(strpos($parts1[$j],$parts2[$i]) !== false) i cant use in_array function

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$filter1 = "red,green,blue,yellow";
$parts1 = explode(',', $filter1);

$filter2 = "red,green,blue,purple";
$parts2 = explode(',', $filter2);

$matching = array_intersect($parts1, $parts2);
$non_matching = array_diff(array_merge($parts1, $parts2), $matching);
```

Changing your code, which should have similar result for non-matching as `array_diff($parts1, $parts2);`

```
for($i=0; $i< count($parts1); $i++)
{
  $is_matching = false;
  for($j=0; $j< count($parts2); $j++)
  {
    if($parts1[$i] == $parts2[$j])
    {
      $is_matching = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if ($is_matching) {
    $match[] = $parts1[$i];
  } else {
    $nomatch[] = $parts1[$i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find matching value using [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and non matching value using [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

Here you can see [LIVE DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a383295f0798ae4afd8b01507fd0932c48780b0d)

```
/**
 * @param $arr
 */
function pr($arr)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
    echo '</pre>';
}

$filter1 = "red,green,blue,yellow";         
$parts1 = explode(',', $filter1);

$filter2 = "red,green,blue";        
$parts2 = explode(',', $filter2);

$match = array_intersect($parts1, $parts2);
$nomatch = array_diff($parts1, $parts2);
pr($match);
pr($nomatch);
```

**Output Screen:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => green
    [2] => blue
)
Array
(
    [3] => yellow
)
```